# Limit Problem with number $e$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm studying for my Calculus 1 final and would like help with the following problem:

> The following limit represents the derivative of some function $f$ at
>   some number $a$: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$$
>
> Write down one possible function $f$ and the corresponding value of
>   $a$. What is the limit?

Do I use integration to get the function f?
Do I use the definition of derivatives?

Comment: Well, (and this is not directed to you, rather to who designed the question), since the limit evaluates to $1$, you can say it's any function whose derivative is $1$ at an $a$ of your choice (and you can imagine this places the feeblest of restrictions to what the function can be).

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities for the function $f$ but the numerator in all these possibilities is

$$f(x)-f(0)=e^x-1\iff f(x)=e^x-1+f(0)$$
so take any value for $f(0)$ say $a$ and the function $f$ is defined by

$$f(x)=e^x-1+a$$

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to\color{brown}0}\dfrac{e^x-e^{\color{brown}0}}{x-\color{brown}0}.$$ Do you see any resemblance with the following? $$f'(a):=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$

Comment: Yup, this makes more sense now! Thank you!

Comment: @Chris You're welcome, glad I could help! :-)